# Celery fanout signals with `send_task`

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to establish communication between different processes running celery. I successfully sent tasks from one process to others using `app.send_task` on a celery instance. I am struggling now to broadcast tasks through a `fanout` rabbitmq exchange to all other instances (basically a publish-subscribe pattern for celery).

It must be related to the routing across exchanges and queues but I simply can't make it work.

This is the master emitter which broadcasts a task named `signal` through the default exchange of type `fanout`:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

app = Celery('emitter',
             broker='pyamqp://test@localhost//',
             backend='db+sqlite:///results.db')


default_queue_name = 'default'
default_exchange_name = 'default'
default_routing_key = 'default'

default_exchange = Exchange(default_exchange_name, type='fanout')
default_queue = Queue(
    default_queue_name,
    default_exchange,
    routing_key=default_routing_key)

app.conf.task_queues = (
    default_queue,
)

app.conf.task_default_queue = default_queue_name
app.conf.task_default_exchange = default_exchange_name
app.conf.task_default_routing_key = default_routing_key


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.send_task(name='signal', exchange='default')
```

To my understanding the routing, queue and exchange setup on the other app needs to be identical. Thus, this is a very similarly looking piece of code but defining a task that gets called:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Exchange, Queue


app = Celery('CLIENT_A',
             broker='pyamqp://test@localhost//',
             backend='db+sqlite:///results.db')


default_queue_name = 'default'
default_exchange_name = 'default'
default_routing_key = 'default'

default_exchange = Exchange(default_exchange_name, type='fanout')
default_queue = Queue(
    default_queue_name,
    default_exchange,
    routing_key=default_routing_key)

app.conf.task_queues = (
    default_queue,
)

app.conf.task_default_queue = default_queue_name
app.conf.task_default_exchange = default_exchange_name
app.conf.task_default_routing_key = default_routing_key


@app.task(name='signal')
def signal():
    print('client_a signal')
    return 'signal'
```

The second client will look exactly the same as the first except for the name and the print message:

```
# [...]

app = Celery('CLIENT_B', ...

# [...] identical to the part above

@app.task(name='signal')
def signal():
    print('client_b signal')
```

I'm starting both client workers with different node names (otherwise celery will complain):

```
celery -A client_a worker -n node_a
celery -A client_b worker -n node_b
```

If I then call the emitter (first piece of code) I see the signals being triggered alternately by client_a and client_b but never both as I would like them to be triggered.

The rabbitmq management platform looks as expected with the default exchange defined as `fanout` and the routing looks alright.

I'm not sure if I'm on the completely wrong track here but that's what I imagined should be possible with correct routing.